# In Beamer, how to prevent \includemovie from restarting swf animations?

Tags: beamer, animations, swf

On this frame, there are 3 swf animations starting once the slide opens. I would like to prevent them from automatically looping. I tried a few options without any success, such as `endat=frame:10` or `repeat=0`.

This behaviour seems to be specific to swf files. I was using mp4 before, which didn't restart automatically. Unfortunately, having three animations on that page caused Adobe Reader to be extremely unstable, which is why I converted the file to swf.

Here is the code:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Example 2}
Double cantilever beam
\vfill
\begin{columns}[l]
   \column{0.33\textwidth}
     \includemovie[autoplay,mouse]{1.\textwidth}{5em}{Pics/Cubic_D_Struct_AnisoShear.swf}
     \small{discrete pre-crack}\\
     \small{cubic function} 
   \column{0.33\textwidth}
     \includemovie[autoplay,mouse]{1.\textwidth}{5em}{Pics/Quad_D_Struct_AnisoShear.swf}
     \small{discrete precrack} \\
     \small{quadratic function} 
   \column{0.33\textwidth}
     \includemovie[autoplay,mouse]{1.\textwidth}{5em}{Pics/Cubic_Struct_AnisoShear.swf}
     \small{modelled pre-crack} \\
     \small{cubic function} 
\end{columns}
\vfill
} %%%
```

Comment: I have no experience on the topic, but could it be related to the fact that only the first is an swf while the other two are mp4?

Comment: You are right about that, I made a mistake. If all three are swf, they all restart automatically. I guess a more accurate question would be: "how to prevent a swf file to automatically restart with `\includemovie`.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: With package `media9` replacing `movie15`, there is no need for conversion of MP4 to SWF.

Comment: @AlexG Please consider posting an answer here to get the question off the unanswered list :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the original MP4/h264 files and the `media9` package.

By default, the video player component `VPlayer.swf` of the `media9` package doesn't loop MP4 video, but rather keeps the last frame after reaching the end.

In the example below, three videos are started right after opening the document/page (thanks to the Flash variable setting `autoPlay=true`). The example uses the files `cube.mp4` and `cubeposter.png` from the `media9` CTAN package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Three Video Example}

\includemedia[
  label=vid1,
  width=0.33\linewidth,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
     source=cube.mp4
    &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\includegraphics{cubeposter}}{VPlayer.swf}\hfill%
\includemedia[
  label=vid2,
  width=0.33\linewidth,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
     source=cube.mp4
    &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\includegraphics{cubeposter}}{VPlayer.swf}\hfill%
\includemedia[
  label=vid3,
  width=0.33\linewidth,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
     source=cube.mp4
    &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\includegraphics{cubeposter}}{VPlayer.swf}

\centerline{\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=vid1:play,
  mediacommand=vid2:play,
  mediacommand=vid3:play
]{\fbox{Play all at once}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```